# Getters and Setters and this. keyword

Tags: java, constructor, getter-setter

I'm new to coding and I'm confused about getters and setters in Java.
I know that getters and setters are used for encapsulation. But if you have a constructor that creates a person of a specific gender and length. Should both of these characteristics have a setter and a getter?

```
public Person(Gender gender, Length length) {
this.gender = gender;
this.length = length;
}
```

Does the this.gender serve as a setter? If no, what's its function?

Do I need to make a getter and setter for these? In code examples i've found they only have a getter, but not a setter. But i don't really understand why.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can define a getter and setter, and you can also not do that. All depends on the control you wish to have over the `Person` object.

Comment: But does the this.gender = gender work as a setter or not? I can't seem to find out what its function is.

Comment: "setter" is just short for "setter method", so is `this.gender = gender` a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In code examples I've found they only have a getter, but not a setter. But I don't really understand why.

The functionality you describe is so when a `Person` object is created, nobody can `set` its `gender` and `length`.
If a user wishes, he/she can create a **new** `Person` (`new Person(...)`) with attributes as they wish. But after a `Person` is created, you cannot `set` the attributes.

> But does the `this.gender = gender` work as a setter or not? I can't seem to find out what its function is.

It does *work* as a setter (though not a setter by itself since it's not a function). But only within the constructor. As I said above.

Note that if the `gender` and `length` fields of a `Person` are not `private` then they can potentially be `set`/`get` outside of a set/get methods.

Comment: So if in my main method i construct a person like this: Person Tom = new Person(male, 183). I have 'set' the length to 183 and the gender to male but i cannot change it anymore?

Comment: Exactly. As long as the `gender` and `length` fields are `private` in the `Person` class as I stated (otherwise the user can just do `myPerson.gender = female` or `myPerson.length = 15` for example).

Comment: Thank you! This question seems silly but i wanted to get the concept straight!

Comment: So can I say that it makes it a final variable? As you can only set it once, at the time you construct the object? Once the object is created, there's no way to change it anymore. Or is this considered wrong?

Comment: Yes, you cannot change a member that is `final`. So in essence when you have no `set` method and the variable is `private` it is implicitly `final` as well. I also suggest you read this: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190955/using-public-final-rather-than-private-getters

Answer (score 1):

The constructor example code you have given is used to set/initialize the variables of Person class when you create Person object by invoking the constructor method. Internally, the attribute values get set by this. So, you can say it's functionality is like setter. After this you only need getters to fetch and use the value held by these attributes.

However, you can also write specific setter method for each attribute to set the values individually for each of them on the same Person object explicitly.

Regards

[Manoj](http://www.gitarani.com/classified.htm?classifiedTypeId=5)

Answer (score 0):

Getter and setter methods in object oriented programming is for controlling the client not to change your variables in an unexpected behavior.

```
public Class Person{
  private int gender;
  private int length;

  public Person(int gender,int length){
    this.gender = gender;
    this.length = length;
  }

  public int getGender(){
     return this.gender;
  }
  public void setGender(int setGender){
     if(setGender==1 || setGender == 0){
       this.gender = setGender;
     }else{
       this.gender = -1;
     }
  }
  public int getLength(){
     return this.length;
  }
  public void setLength(int setLength){
     if(setLength>100){
       this.length = setLength;
     }else{
       this.length = -1;
     }
  }
}
```

like in this code sample, if you have some constraints about your variables and you need to dictate client to update these variables in your way, you should use getter and setter methods in order to control your variables updating way.

In this example, if the client's gender is different from 0 or 1 (if it enters invalid gender code) we are assigning -1 to its variable in order to see that invalid gender, length logic is also same.